# Too many MySQL connections on WordPress

Tags: server-load

I installed Wordpress on my Ubuntu server. I only have 3 blog posts but it reaches `max_connection` within an hour. So whenever a user visits my blog it shows a database establish error. My log file has the following entry:

`server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Mon Jun 20 06:30:21.877663 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 43436] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

My default `max_connection` is 200 now. I increased it to 1024. 
Once i increase `max_connection` to 1024 it works fine. But I think that it's not the real issue. For three blogs it makes 564 connections.

Comment: This sounds like you have some loop-in-a-loop or something similar… Do you have any custom plugins/themes activated that could cause this behavior?

Comment: i disable all my plugins and use default wordpress template